# Mutable array/list memory size

Tags: arrays, memory, arraylist, memory-management

If I recall correctly, the initialization of a fixed array with a length of `8` of object type `int` will reserve a memory block the size of `(8 * size_of_int)` at compile time.

How does memory management work for initialization of dynamic/mutable arrays, whose length can change at run time?

Comment: Your question is open-ended, so I don't really know if this will help... The simple answer is that the memory is allocated through some method that communicates with the OS to manage available memory.  Generally this pool of memory is  called the "heap".  In C, this functionality is provided by the malloc() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change length of array at the run time called dynamic memory allocation. When you need to increase the size of array, the System will release the previous memory and allocate the new memory for new length and assign the first element address into your pointer variable.

You can read more about Dynamic memory allocation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation